# 360 video embed on iOS

Tags: html, 360-virtual-reality

the Vimeo and YouTube players don’t natively support 360 video when embedded. How can we make this work?

Embedding shows equirectangular view on iOS but it works everywhere else

Built in react with clips coming from contentful/vimeo

Here is the website: http://preview.theconfectionery.design
Vr videos work fine on iPad/desktop but not on iOS.

I was hoping we could use google VR view’s iframe code but it doesn’t seem to have any effect, video still plays back equirectangular.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.